# Minerd not showing boo or yay

Tags: miner-configuration, mac, cpu-mining

I ran
`./minerd -a sha256d -o stratum+tcp://stratum.f2pool.com:3333 -u (my username).node1`. Here is a sample of the output:

`[2015-07-05 07:15:23] thread 1: 146649416 hashes, 2332 khash/s
[2015-07-05 07:15:24] thread 2: 146553656 hashes, 2336 khash/s
[2015-07-05 07:15:25] thread 0: 146977944 hashes, 2332 khash/s
[2015-07-05 07:16:34] thread 3: 140158460 hashes, 1976 khash/s
[2015-07-05 07:16:34] thread 2: 140169760 hashes, 1986 khash/s
[2015-07-05 07:16:34] thread 1: 139945520 hashes, 1968 khash/s
[2015-07-05 07:16:36] thread 0: 139935536 hashes, 1979 khash/s
[2015-07-05 07:17:27] thread 1: 118086220 hashes, 2251 khash/s
[2015-07-05 07:17:27] thread 2: 119150888 hashes, 2247 khash/s
[2015-07-05 07:17:27] thread 3: 118589808 hashes, 2228 khash/s
[2015-07-05 07:17:29] thread 0: 118715120 hashes, 2241 khash/s
[2015-07-05 07:18:25] thread 3: 133685248 hashes, 2320 khash/s
[2015-07-05 07:18:25] thread 2: 134829324 hashes, 2331 khash/s
[2015-07-05 07:18:25] thread 1: 135066588 hashes, 2305 khash/s
[2015-07-05 07:18:27] thread 0: 134440760 hashes, 2324 khash/s
[2015-07-05 07:19:26] thread 1: 138319856 hashes, 2290 khash/s
[2015-07-05 07:19:26] thread 3: 139194024 hashes, 2283 khash/s
[2015-07-05 07:19:26] thread 2: 139838276 hashes, 2284 khash/s
[2015-07-05 07:19:27] thread 0: 139453064 hashes, 2298 khash/s`
It just stays like this, with no yays or boos... What am I doing wrong?
(OS X Yosemite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F2Pool (along with most today) don't offer share difficulties low enough for CPU mining, in this case the default is 1024. It will take on average one week to mine a single share at this point in time, and it will pay out less than 100th of a Satoshi (0.0000000001 BTC, 0.00000002608 USD) for the CPU time expended. CPU mining has been unprofitable since 2010 as the power costs for doing it are many orders of magnitude higher than the income you can make doing it.